# Alternating the direction of motor spin using navigator.vibrator

Tags: javascript, html, api

How do i make the motor (vibarator)vibrate towards the opposite direction using javascript.?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, you might want to check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Vibration API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Vibration_API) has no concept of "direction" (nor is it likely the underlying hardware does).